why ubuntu doesn't succeeds to connect to paired headset?
My headset are paired to bluetooth on ubuntu (24.04.1 LTS), but when I click on connect the operation fails. Each time I want to connect I must disconnect the earphones (from the paired devices list) and repair it again.
How to solve this issue?

Root cause cannot be determined from the provided info.
Try modify the mac below, then run it, to reconnenct...
#!/bin/env bash

mac="F0:0B:AD:C0:DE" # check: Settings, Bluetooth, click on connected device

on="bluetoothctl connect $mac";
off="bluetoothctl disconnect $mac";

echo $off;
$off;
echo "sleep 2";
sleep 2;
echo $on;
$on

Alternative for $on / $off
on="rfkill unblock bluetooth";
off="rfkill block bluetooth"

